# How to prove that the induced surface charge on a conductor is univocally determined?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, conductors

Suppose we have a conductor $\Omega$ and a charge distribution $\rho$ *outside* said conductor in free space. Elementary electrostatics tells us that $\rho$ will cause the free charges inside $\Omega$ to reach the surface, thus inducing a surface charge density $\sigma$ on $\partial \Omega$ so as to cancel off the electric field inside the conductor.

Now, all sources I've consulted explicitly state that $\sigma$ is *univocally determined*, but never include a proof of this fact. I found this strange, considering that said sources use such fact to provide a proper definition of capacitance.

I think that it someway boils down to Poisson equation, but I honestly can't come up with a proof.

So how would one prove it?

Comment: If you treat the electric fields as known and the charge distribution as unknown then Poisson's equation is essentially already solved. You just plug in the $E$ field, differentiate and read off $\rho = \epsilon_0 \nabla\cdot \mathbf{E}$.

Comment: But I don't treat the electric field as known (except inside the conductor, where it is null). Only $\rho$ and the geometry of $\Omega$ are known.

Comment: *univocally* or *unequivocally*?

Comment: @JohnRennie here's a literal translation from Italian of the passage in a textbook I'm using: "[...] the charge distribution that makes the field inside the conductor null, and hence the potential constant, is one and one only"

Comment: Is it possible that the total charge $Q$ of the conductor is $0$, considering that, as a whole, it should be neutral?